# Best way to bypass certain piece of code

Tags: apex

In my project, we are migrating big chunk of functionality from one salesforce instance to another.

While doing obviously we are getting all data from Old instance to new instance. There are some class where we are invoking a method which will send emails ( say using send email salesforce functionality).

Now only on production release day we will do one time data migration of old record.

I want to Bypass this piece of logic which is sending the Send Email.

Right Now to achieve this I have created one custom setting and created record as 'Bypass_Notification' and the kept value to False. On prod release day, i will set it to true so that this piece of logic will not run during migration.

Is there any better way to tackle this? The reason why I am posting is, it's a custom Setting and If some one messes up the value in future, this send email functionality will be hampered.

This is not only for Send email. we have other logic which will some how notifies Users, Notifies other integrated systems. I don't want that to happen. Just one day i need to bypass certain logic.

Comment: Normally after deployment, after few days when I feel the system is stable, I delete the custom settings. Part of code cleanups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having recently gone through something similar when adding nearly 400 new users to an existing 1800 user org, I have some experience and thoughts I'll add to what others have posted. We were also going through a data migration at the time and had to turn off many (new) triggers every time data was being migrated.

Custom Settings are the "traditional" way that developers have added a lot of this kind of functionality. There's a new and perhaps "better" way to do this that you should consider for several reasons. The first and most important is that unlike custom settings data, any "settings" you create can be migrated to sandboxes very easily. What I'm speaking of and recommending is that you use "Custom Metadata".

If you use Custom Metadata, you'll have detail pages you can use to configure and create these settings. You'll also be able to complete "Help" fields to explain what the settings do. Once completed, you can create permission sets to provide access for only those users who'll know how/when to change them.

Metadata is what the platform runs on. It's quickly accessed and queries for it don't cost you anything. This is the way I recommend you do what you're asking about when you want to "flip" a switch to turn some feature "on" or "off".

Comment: Thanks crmprogdev the reason why I am voting this as best is, as said by you, having those records created in Custom Metadata gives more flexibility Like( Hiding the field in layouts,having validations rules etc). But only one problem we have here is , we need to query them everytime when we need to access ( At least 1 DML is needed have those recs)

Comment: Understand, but you get that access via the query for free on custom metadata.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `Email Deliverability` and define `Access Level` as `No Access` to prevent emails being sent to users.

This way, you don't need to change the code or deactivate triggers or workflow rules.

Ideally, if you choose this option then migrate the data during off business hours.

For more information, refer [Guidelines for Configuring Deliverability Settings for Emails Sent from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 1):

While this is a broad topic and how you want to implement. But you definitely should **have your data migration tested on a sandbox** (preferably full copy) before attempting that on Production directly. With this test, you will be able to know what are those logic that are getting executed after the data is loaded as well as what are the steps that you want to take to stop anything to get executed.

This also is a best practice to make sure all your migration scripts works fine and that you are able to troubleshoot any data related errors upfront instead of waiting until the release date.

And for your approach to use custom setting, you can have this logic very well tested when you do in a sandbox instead of directly doing it in Production and putting things at risk. You will also be able to identify if you need it say in one class vs. any other classes.

There are other ways to bypass any logic too, as if you have a cleansed data, and that you don't want any further action upon its load, then you may like to disable any triggers, workflow rules, etc. during data load and only enable it after your loads have taken place.

Answer (score 1):

**Hierarchy** custom settings is the approach I followed in my current project.

We enable/disable validation rules and triggers based on values set on the **USER** level. This way you have more control and you can also run migrations while the users still use the system without loosing functionality.

As you mentioned, this imposes a risk of somebody setting an Org wide setting and bypassing all notifications for all the users. Admins can anyway kill your org in many ways, so if you have the right people and you make sure the knowledge is transferred you shouldn't worry (that much...)